# Getting the application current locale

Tags: android, locale, android-context, multilingual

I need to get application current locale to show formatted date regarding this value. I use following code to get locale info from context:

```
fun getCurrentLocale(context: Context): Locale {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        context.resources.configuration.locales.get(0)
    } else {

        context.resources.configuration.locale
    }
}
```

Actually those code works fine, but if I will change language twice code returns old information. Like this: set "en" , then set "rus" and then set "en" again and when I will call

> "getCurrentLocale"

"rus" will be returned.  The main point here is that application changes language , it I will call following code in the same line :

```
    `Log.e("transated", getString(R.string.wallet))`
```

"wallet" will be translated correctly.

Comment: What about storing your date formats in `strings.xml` so that you don't have to ever check the current locale? You can just call `getString()`

Comment: I can't understand what you mean? I need to show dynamic dates by language